# Can't properly install GTK theme on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: themes, gtk

I have installed GNOME on Ubuntu 16.04 using the "sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop" command. When I try to change the GTK+ theme using the "Gnome tweak tool" I have a weird behaviour:

With the preinstalled Numix theme:
[Numix theme: ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yELRs.png)

With the installed Juno theme:
[Juno theme: not ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq9JK.png)

I have looked for answers on the Web but nothing... This happens with any theme that i download.

Thank you

Edit: Going to "About" does not give me any information on the GNOME version Im running, but if I go to

> /usr/share/gnome/gnome-version.xml

then i get this [gnome version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gvaox.png)

Comment: The theme should be looking like this: https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1280977/

Comment: you're probably going to be using metacity to change to the theme (notably for window borders and buttons). this may be an issue of the theme being for gnome 3 and on ubuntu 16.04 you may only get gnome 2 if you open up your activities or settings and got to "about" what do you get ? I have this : https://imgur.com/Z2ZULSV or find another method to fidn out your gnome version. edit your original post to incude the result.